# Where to store UNIVERSAL methods in Perl

Tags: perl, oop, methods

So I understand that the special UNIVERSAL class is to be considered the base class from which all other objects are created. So if a specific method is not found after Perl traverses the inheritance hierarchy, it will look in the UNIVERSAL class to see if the method can be found there. However, when you create a distribution, no UNIVERSAL.pm package is created. Also, the UNIVERSAL methods 'DOES' and 'can' already exist without a UNIVERSAL.pm...  As such, I am not sure if I should be writing UNIVERSAL methods into random packages like so:

```
sub UNIVERSAL::nicemethod{
    launch_teh_missles();
}
```

Or should I be creating a separate UNIVERSAL package and .pm file? What is considered best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You can add new methods to UNIVERSAL the same way as to any other package:

```
package
   UNIVERSAL;  # Line break to fool CPAN indexer

sub nice_method {
   ...
}
```

Comment: You don't want CPAN to believe your distro has a module named UNIVERSAL, so you want to put a line break in the `package` directive.

Comment: does that also mean it is not wise to create a UNIVERSAL.pm file for the methods?